# Spring Bean validation giving ConstraintDeclarationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, hibernate-validator

I am getting javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000197: No value extractor found for type parameter 'T' of type reactor.core.publisher.Mono.
I am getting this after adding @Validated at class level. If I remove this no validation logic triggers.

```
  @RestController
  @Validated
  public class ContactInfoController implements ContactInfoApi {
  public Flux<UserContactsModel> getUserContacts(@RequestBody  Mono<@Valid  LoginModel> loginDetail) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message that you get is actually an expected behavior, as there's no `ValueExtractor` registered in HV. These value extractors are required by Bean Validation when the value should be extracted from some container. 
For more details on ValueExtractors please see this [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-valueextraction)

In your particular case `Mono` is treated as a container. But the concept of `Mono` (`Subscriber`) is not the same as a container. And I don't see how you could mix these two concepts together. To be able to "validate" a mono you would actually need to wrap its `subscribe` method with some validation proxy and perform the validation when a value is pushed to the mono itself.